# hide section numbering but continue adding-up

Tags: sectioning, numbering

When I hide a section with the asterisk it doesn't show the number in the heading and the section doesn't show up in the TOC.

How to hide a section but have the counter beeing added-up correctly so that `\thesection` gives the correct number of the section?

Comment: Do you use a documentclass which is provided by `KOMA`? Then you can use `addchap` or `addsec`

Comment: `\setcounter{section}{12}` allows me to set the counter manually. But I'm looking for a more comfy way to only *hide* the number or even better allow me to place the number in the heading manually or leave it completly out.

Comment: @Marco: I guess he likes to have the counter incremented even though the number isn’t displayed … and that’s not what `\addchap` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’ think there’s a finished macro/package for that but you can increment the counter either with `\stepcounter{section}` or with `\refstepcounter{section}` which increments the counter and updates the belonging `\ref`-lables.

So If you need a command for this try

```
\newcommand{\unnumsec}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}\section*{#1}}
```

or if you’re using KOMA-Script

```
\newcommand{\unnumsec}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}\addsec{#1}}
```

The main difference between `\section*` and `\addsec` is that the latter also sets the headmarks and generates a ToC entry, where `\section*` only prints text formatted like the section headline. (See the [scrguien.pdf](http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) [or the german [scrguide](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguide.pdf)] for more information about `\addsec` command)

Answer (score 4):

Adapting the answer from this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex):

Option 1 (use `\section*`, then `\addtocounter` to increment section counter):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{uno}
\section{dos}
\section*{hide}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\section{tres}
\end{document}
```

Option 2 (suppress `\addcontentsline` temporarily):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{uno}
\section{dos}
\tocless\section{hide}
\section{tres}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would need `\numberless` then..

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you say "even better allow me to place the number in the heading manually or leave it completly out".

That one's easy:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
```

The `section` counter gets incremented, but no number is displayed. (You still get the number in the TOC, though; not sure if you want that.)

Comment: No I want to place the section number individually in the section heading `\section{This is \thesection . approach}`. Not sure how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I use this redefined command to create sections without numbering but it keeps adding-up:

```
\newcommand{\sect}[1] {\section*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\addtocounter{section}{1}}
```

Also in table of contents, of course.

Comment: Also you can change `\addtocounter{section}{1}` with `\stepcounter{section}` to better enumeration.