# Generate table of contents when \section* (sections without numbering) has been used

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, starred-version

Is it possible just to generate a table of contents based on sections in asterisk mode, i.e., `\section*`?  I basically just want the table of contents without section numbers.  Like a list of headings and their associated pages.

The following doesn't generate a ToC:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subsection*{Section 1}

\subsection*{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You don't have numbered sections, do you? In this case the simplest arrangement is

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\section{Second}
```

No sectional unit below `\section` will be numbered, but sections and subsections will go anyway in the table of contents (as this depends on the value of the `tocdepth` counter, default 2).

Comment: Suppose I don't want numbering for headings at any level, how would I modify your solution?  Keep in mind I do still want a table of contents, just without heading numbering...

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` will remove the numbering also for parts (and all levels below).

Comment: This is a good solution - very minimal and unobtrusive, without any compromise.  :)

Comment: You are a hero. Take my internet points.

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me. I still get the numbered sections and subsections. Could it be due to the fact that I use a template and a master file including chapter files? Do I have to insert `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` in a special place?

Comment: @FrankEjbyPoulsen Try just after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, the headers still display the section names with a number, although it is the chapter number +0. Do you know how to cancel this as well?

Comment: @FrankEjbyPoulsen I think it's better to make a fresh question with a MWE.

Comment: This solution actually has a problem for me: the pdf indexing now fails to work, i.e., it doesn't jump to the corresponding section when I click on the entries of the TOC.

Comment: alright, it turns out that it is the customization using the package titlesec that breaks hyperref. loading hyperref after my customization solves the problem.

Comment: It still shows numbers for "sections"

Comment: @Ahmad Not in my tests. What class are you using?

Answer (score 56):

The following is a manual way of adding entries to the table of contents by means of `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Section 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Section 1}%
\section*{Section 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Section 2}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Starred sections in ToC]

The reason for using `\numberline{}` is to allow for the traditional numbered space in the table of contents. If you're not interested in this numeric alignment, then you can drop the `\protect\numberline{}`.

Comment: Thanks! The advantage of this approach is that it allows combining sections and section*s in a straightforward manner

Answer (score 9):

Adapting [DevSolar's answer from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30039/hide-section-numbering-but-continue-adding-up/30047#30047) (clearing out the definition of `\thesection`), and assuming you don't really care if you use `\section*`, you just want to remove numbers from the headings and ToC entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A Section}
\section{Another Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - this seems like a fairly succinct solution - and moreover it works, though would you mind explaining what is happening?  I don't understand why/how this works.

Comment: In many cases, `\theX` is a macro that prints the number of the current document division (where 'X' is chapter, section, subsection, etc.) Clearing it out prevents it from being printed. However, on further examination, this doesn't suppress the space between the number and the division title, and the section headings get indented more than I'd like. So I'd go with egreg's version instead.

Comment: This is a nice option. However, in my case, it leaves a blank space where there was supposed to be the number of the section, subsection etc. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: As I'd indicated, I'd go with egreg's solution over mine.

Answer (score 1):

what about using

\addsec{}

instead of

\section*{}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you extend your answer a bit to explain what is the difference between the two commands? Also, the OP uses the `article` class, and I think `\addsec` is only available in the KOMA classes.

Comment: With the added info that `\addsec` needs a KOMA script class and ideally a short example document demonstrating its use and effects (based on the MWE in the question) this could be a great answer.