# Lyx - remove section numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

Is there a way to remove section numbering, while maintaining subsection etc. numbering? For example, I want in my TOC to have "Lecture 1", not "1 Lecture 1", but still have subsection numbering as "1.1 subsection title" or "1 subsection title" or anything like that, under section 1.

Comment: You can manually use `*` and `\addcontentsline` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30123/124842

Answer (score 1):

You may use instead of `\section{Lecture 1}`, `\section*{Lecture 1}`, it removes the numbering. This also applies to `\subsection{}` and similar sectioning macros.