# ToC for colored and unnumbered sections

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex

I need to make a layout in which the section headers are colored and appear in the ToC. So far no problem. The next requirement is to skip numbering. My attempt in luaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coi_gray}{RGB}{136,155,169}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{coi_gray}}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % <---- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30225/48642
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % prints Table of Contents
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-14]
\section{First long text}
\lipsum[8-20]
\section{Second long text}
\lipsum[8-20]

\end{document}
```

I tried to follow the [solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30122/48642) but now I'm facing that the ToC link incorrectly - either to page 1 or some random page. The other solutions like `\addcontentsline` suffer the same problem and `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}` has odd spacing in the section.

Using titlesec from 2016-03-21.

Comment: couple of remarks: `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package (very few exceptions – most notable `cleveref`). Present version of `titlesec` is 2.13, dated from 2019/10/16.

Comment: What is not clear is whether you want sections to be unnumbered in text and in the table of contents, or only in table of contents?

Comment: ahaaa... loading the `hyperref` after the `titlesec` solves the issue. Thx. I want the unnumbered section in ToC and in the text.

Comment: Nevertheless, you should update titlesec (and perhaps other packages, if you haven't done it for a long tme).

Comment: @Bernard one of you could formulate this into an answer, so that LeO can mark the question as answered.